# Change <td> to <th> in first row of a HTML table server side using Cold Fusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion-9, tablecell

I am sending a HTML string to the Cold Fusion (9) server. The string contains a HTML table with multiple rows. Since the table doesn't have a head I need to change the `<td>`s of the first row into `<th>`s.

For your information:
The code to change is a paste code coming from MS Word. The code gets sent to the server to check if there are any tables in it. If yes, there is an option dialog shown to the user where he can descide how the table will be formatted (striped, hovers and so on).

In my opinion the best way to do that would be ReReplace(). But I can't figure what the right regex can be.
Any suggestions on that will be much appreciated.

The code looks like:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Head 1</td><td>Head 2</td><td>Head 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Content 1 Row 1</td><td>Content 2 Row 1</td><td>Content 3 Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Content 1 Row 2</td><td>Content 2 Row 2</td><td>Content 3 Row 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And should look like:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr><th>Head 1</th><th>Head 2</th><th>Head 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>Content 1 Row 1</td><td>Content 2 Row 1</td><td>Content 3 Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Content 1 Row 2</td><td>Content 2 Row 2</td><td>Content 3 Row 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you mind to provide code - the current code and how the code is supposed to look like?

Comment: Is changing the table generating code not an option?

Comment: Sorry for not providing code. Here it is. And I've added some explaination for why I need it.

Answer (score 1):

**Obligatory warning:** maybe a parser or as @npinti suggested changing the output in the first place is a far better way to go.
That being said, you could use a lazy quantifier (expensive!) between the `<td>` tags and feed the function chunks of `<table>` parts and substitute it with `<th>\2</th>` (see the [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD7nO3/2) for an example).

```
(<td>(.*?)<\/td>)
```

**Hint:** This does not take additional attributes into account (e.g. `class="test123"`).

Comment: Thank you. I solved it parsing the tables using Rematch() and altering the first row.